# How to POST cross-domain form data using DOJO

Tags: dojo, cross-domain

I want to send form data using POST method to a remote URL using DOJO.
dojo.xhrPost works for local domain & dojo.io.script.get is only for GET method.

Can anyone suggest me a method to do this?

Shiji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use dojo.io.iframe to accomplish this:

```
dojo.io.iframe.send({
  url: 'www.myawesome.server',
  form: form,
  content: content
});
```

But apparently you need to set the method on the form to POST:

```
dojo.attr(form, 'method', 'post');
```

(Or do it directly on the form: `<form method="post" ...>`)

I haven't tried this, but here is an article describing exactly what (I believe) you are trying to do:

http://www.mikejuniper.com/2009/03/fun-with-dojoioiframesend/

Comment: i tried this one, but I get a response from the url, which says that a mandatory parameter is missing. I am using both the form & content fields of dojo.io.iframe.send(). Will this cause any issue? I had set that paremter in the content part as well as in my form(in a hidden field).  What could be the issue?

Comment: This is how i call dojo.io.iframe.send
dojo.io.iframe.send({
 url: url,
        form: formNode,
 content: content,
 method: 'POST',
 handleAs: "json",
 reventCache: true,
 load: cb,
 error: cb
});

The content is set as follows:
var content = {
 PassKey : "xxxxx",
 apiversion : "5.0",
 Action : "submit",
 ProductId : catEntryId,
 Title : title,
 ReviewText : body,
 Rating : rating,
 itemDescription : description,
 UserId : "apocalypto",
 UserNickname : "apocalypto"
}

Comment: The mandatory parameter from the server has got to be an issue with the application on the server:  it is just responding that the client didn't send something it needed.  The request itself is working properly, but you are not sending something the server-side wants.

Comment: Will i be able to do the POST like this? dojo.io.iframe.send(jsonpArgs).then(function(resp) { /*some call back code*/} ??
the call is not getting into my callback part. what could be the issue?

Comment: hm, I would try using the `load` param on your arguments, and see if that gets called.  I'm not sure if `dojo.io.iframe.send` returns a deferred the way you are expecting it to.